Can PAM set home directory to a substring of the username?
I'm using pam (via authd) to have users log into Azure VMs (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS) using their Azure AD username, which is their email address. So they log in with, say, ssh bill@foo.com@my_vm_ip. This works.
Their username on the VM is bill@foo.com and their home directory is /home/bill@foo.com.
We only have one domain, and we want the home directory to be just the name part of their email address (e.g., /home/bill).
I've tried creating a script to export HOME=/home/${USER%@*} and call that script from within /etc/pam.d/sshd, but nothing seems to work.
Is there a way to set a user's home directory to just their name instead of their entire email address?
